# Launching Wizard from ListView after selecting elements odoo8

Tags: odoo-8, wizard

my mission is to select several elements from the list view than click on "show wizard button" that is added to "more" option !
My code bellow adds the button but not in the ListView, but accually after clicking of the element and showing the formView!

Mytestmodule.wizard.py :

```
class wiz(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'mytestmodule.wizard'
    name=fields.Text()    
    @api.multi    
    def create_request(self):
        print "You click finish"
        return True
```

My wizard form :

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="mywiz" >   
 <field name="name">mywiz</field>       
 <field name="model">mytestmodule.wizard</field>          
 <field name="arch" type="xml">            
 <form string="my wizard">          
 <group>                  
 <field name="name"/>           
 </group>                 
 <footer>                  
 <button name="create_request" string="Finished" type="object"   class="btn-primary"/>     
 <button string="Cancel"  class="btn-default"  special="cancel" />  
 </footer>              
 </form>         
 </field>      
 </record>
```

The added button :

```
<act_window id ="addedButton" name="Show wizard"
res_model="mytestmodule.wizard" 
src_model="mytestmodule.people" 

view_type="tree"            
view_mode="form"
target="new"
 />
```

I know it must be something missing or had to change in  tag ! but i have no idea how to do so .
Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding multi="True" attribute in  tag :

```
<act_window id ="addedButton"
            name="Show wizard"
            res_model="account_voucher_bymail.wizard"
            src_model="account.invoice"
            view_type="tree"
            view_mode="tree,form"
            target="new"
            multi="True"
             />
```